Does increasing gas solubility rate reduce the increase of pressure when adding gas to a closed system?
Whilst I have tried to put the question in a generic form in the title, this actually relates to a specific scenario (from the realm of homebrewing, of all places) and I think I should outline that scenario to best explain what I mean.
Imagine one wants to quickly carbonate a liquid (such as a failed batch of beer) and the only material on hand is a quantity of dry ice (solid CO2). People online have tried adding carefully measured quantities of dry ice to containers of beer and sealing them. However one such pioneer advised shaking the container vigorously once the dry ice is added to avoid the dry ice subliming too fast to be dissolved into the liquid, causing a pressure buildup in the gas space of the container and thus risking the integrity of the container.
Now, this sounds fishy to me but goes beyond my school-level condensced matter physics. If the dry ice sublimed completely in the gaseous headspace, would it exert more pressure than if it was dissolved in the liquid? Would the rate of solution be a limiting factor given typical quantities of CO2 and properties of beer bottles? As far as I'm aware from passing experience with soda-streams and such things, carbonation is normally an effectively instantaneous process.
